# Correctly using stacktrace to debug

Tags: c#, exception, stack-trace

The following line of code is causing me an Exception

`plug.Instance.AddDocuments(new Int32[] { val_pid }, val_ptype, val_doccat, val_subcat, val_doctype, val_notes, val_summary, SummaryAppendOptions.None, val_docStatus, new String[] { PDFFile })`

And this is the exception detail.

```
System.Exception was caught
 Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object. - Error when trying to save    document
 Source=SimsBridge

 StackTrace:
   at SimsBridge.Bridge.AddDocuments(Int32[] personIds, Int32 PersonType, String docCatagory, Int32 subCatagory, String docType, String notes, String summary, SummaryAppendOptions summaryOptions, String documentStatusCode, String[] filePaths)
   at ManagedScanDesktop.Form1.SimsScanComplete(String[] files) in C:\Working\ManagedScanDesktop 1.8\v1.8\ManagedScanDesktop\ManagedScanDesktop\Form1.cs:line 2619
InnerException:
```

I'm not looking for a solution to the actual exception.

My question is, does the stacktrace point to which part of the method doesn't have a reference set? Or is stacktrace just to trace to where the method is called?

Comment: Its the second statement you're saying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stack trace shows you the call stack when an exception is thrown. From what you've provided you can only deduce that an exception was thrown from `AddDocuments`. Any of the reference type parameters passed in could be null. The best way to pinpoint the problems is to set a breakpoint and than inspect the values.

Comment: If that is the case, why wouldn't the stack trace show the corresponding line inside the "AddDocuments" method?

Comment: This is correct, I have checked it. The stack trace tells you the function call and the line number where the error occurs, not the line itself. My answer was wrong then.

Comment: @Arun I think because it's a "call" stack, most likely the exception was thrown during some code that was trying to use a null object so the target method never gets invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Your stack trace means that either SimsBridge or SimsBridge.Bridge is null.

Comment: The StackTrace is saying that something inside `SimsBridge.Bridge` is null

Answer (score 1):

The message is telling you that somewhere in `AddDocuments` a null reference exception was thrown. It could be one of the parameters or a member.